# Google Chrome Pinch gesture to magnify instead of zooming

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, gestures

on my work notebook, when I pinch touchpad in Chrome, I'm getting magnification effect (no layout change), but on my private notebook I'm getting a zoom level change (with page layout change) and I can't find info on how to change it.

I'm really used to magnification as it is waaaay faster then zoom level change.

Does anyone know how to enable it?
Is it somehow hardware related, as both notebooks are running on Windows 10?

**[Update]**
The only difference I notice between both laptops is that in the private one, Windows touchpad settings are missing (3/4 finger settings), probably due to drivers.

I've followed that lead and a bit of googling I found video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2rfwR-IV-c
I have Asus Q400A  and  I've installed Elan drivers and it works like a charm :)

Best regards